# what is a better way to organize nested conditional statements in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find a simpler way to have my program produce a sentence with multiple outcomes. I want to also include either a "comma" or a "and" in between the statements depending on if there are only those 2 or it is the last one in the sequence. A point in the right direction would help.

A full positive sentence is "After viewing the video the individual was compliant, had good judgment, was responsible, showed good customer service, and showed safe practices"

a full sentence "After viewing the video the individual had good judgment, showed good customer service, and showed safe practices, unfortunately the individual was not compliant and was irresponsible."

I have looked into using a power set for what I have but it seems like that would be more work.

```
Function VidSent2(HeShe, Vcomp, Vjudg, Vresp, Vcust, Vsafe)
'HeShe is just to see if it should use "he" or "she"

Pstmt1 = "": Nstmt1 = ""
Pstmt2 = "": Nstmt2 = "": a1 = "": c1 = ""
Pstmt3 = "": Nstmt3 = "": a2 = "": c2 = ""
Pstmt4 = "": Nstmt4 = "": a3 = "": c3 = ""
Pstmt5 = "": Nstmt5 = "": a4 = "": c4 = "" 

A = 0

If Vcomp = True Then
    Pstmt1 = "was compliant" ' what comes after this? , or and?
    A = A + 1
Else
    Nstmt1 = "was not compliant"
End If

If Vjudg = True Then
    Pstmt2 = "had good judgment"
    A = A + 1
Else
    Nstmt2 = "had bad judment"
End If

If Vresp = True Then
    Pstmt2 = "was responsible"
    A = A + 1
Else
    Nstmt2 = "was not responsible"
End If

If Vcust = True Then
    Pstmt2 = "showed good customer service"
    A = A + 1
Else
    Nstmt2 = "showed bad customer service"
End If

If Vsafe = True Then
    Pstmt2 = "showed safe practices."
    A = A + 1
Else
    Nstmt2 = "did not show safe practices."
End If

End If

'might need to return a text value
bmRange.Text = Pstmt1 & c1 & a1 & Pstmt2 & c2 & a2 & Pstmt3 & c3 & a3 &     Pstmt4 & c4 & a4 & Pstmt5 & c5 & a5 & "unfortunately " & HeShe & _
Nstmt1 & Nstmt2 & Nstmt3 & Nstmt4 & Nstmt5

'after viewing the video i observed the individual "
'had good judgment ", unfortunately "heshe"...
'was compliant " and " had good judgment
'was compliant ", " had good judgment " and " was responsible

 end function
```

there are 32 potential outcomes for the sentence depending if they are on the left side of the "unfortunately" or the right side. (The case where they all are on one side or all on the other side are already accounted for.) I am trying to add it whether to include a comma after the statement or a "and".

Also the code I posted is a "work in progress" because I want to see if there is a better way to do it instead of brute forcing which seems to be the way that I am headed. It doesn't include code for the commas or "and" yet.

EDIT: What I ended up choosing to do was take MacroPod's answer and tweak it a bit (I am aware I can clean it up and will do so in the future. It does what I need to do roughly.) Thank you everyone who helped.

```
Function VidSent2(Comp As Boolean, Judg As Boolean, Resp As Boolean, Cust As Boolean, Safe As Boolean)
Dim ArrPos(), ArrNeg(), StrOut As String
ReDim Preserve ArrPos(0): ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(0): StrOut = ""

If Comp = True Then
    If UBound(ArrPos) >= 0 Then
        ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = "was compliant"
        ReDim Preserve ArrPos(0 To UBound(ArrPos) + 1)
    End If
Else
    If UBound(ArrNeg) >= 0 Then
        ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = "was not compliant"
        ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(0 To UBound(ArrNeg) + 1)
    End If
End If

If Judg = True Then
    If UBound(ArrPos) >= 0 Then
        ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = "had good judgment"
        ReDim Preserve ArrPos(0 To UBound(ArrPos) + 1)
    End If
Else
    If UBound(ArrNeg) >= 0 Then
        ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = "had bad judgment"
        ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(0 To UBound(ArrNeg) + 1)
    End If
End If

If Resp = True Then
    If UBound(ArrPos) >= 0 Then
        ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = "was responsible"
        ReDim Preserve ArrPos(0 To UBound(ArrPos) + 1)
    End If
Else
    If UBound(ArrNeg) >= 0 Then
        ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = "was not responsible"
        ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(0 To UBound(ArrNeg) + 1)
    End If
End If

If Cust = True Then
    If UBound(ArrPos) >= 0 Then
        ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = "showed good customer service"
        ReDim Preserve ArrPos(0 To UBound(ArrPos) + 1)
    End If
Else
    If UBound(ArrNeg) >= 0 Then
        ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = "showed bad customer service"
        ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(0 To UBound(ArrNeg) + 1)
    End If
End If

If Safe = True Then
    If UBound(ArrPos) >= 0 Then
        ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = "showed safe practices"
        ReDim Preserve ArrPos(0 To UBound(ArrPos) + 1)
    End If
Else
    If UBound(ArrNeg) >= 0 Then
        ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = "did not show safe practices"
        ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(0 To UBound(ArrNeg) + 1)
    End If
End If
ReDim Preserve ArrPos(0 To UBound(ArrPos) - 1)
ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(0 To UBound(ArrNeg) - 1)
If UBound(ArrPos) > 0 Then ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = "and " & ArrPos(UBound (ArrPos))
If UBound(ArrNeg) > 0 Then ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = "and " & ArrNeg(UBoun(ArrNeg))

If ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) <> "" Then StrOut = "After viewing the video the individual " & Join(ArrPos(), ", ") & "."

If ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) <> "" Then StrOut = StrOut & " Unfortunately, the individual still " & Join(ArrNeg(), ", ") & "."

VidSent2 = StrOut
End Function
```

Comment: Could you write the whole sentence for e.g. all 'Trues'? You can edit your answer, Right below your post there is the edit button so you could add it there. If not put it in a comment.

Comment: it would help if the code sample would declare all variables *with* their data types. Overs the decades I've learned making assumptions as to data types is often a bad idea... It's also a good idea to have `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module, which is obviously not the case, here.

Comment: I would be inclined to create separate *functions* for each test, descriptively named so that it's obvious what each test is for. This will make working out the logic easier and it will also make it easier to change building the result if a component is later added or removed from the sentence being built. So `IsCompliant` for example would return the `String` appropriate to `VComp`, and pass `A` as `byRef` to the function for incrementation (or not). I'd also give `A` a more descriptive name - someone else might need to maintain this later, so it should be as self-documenting as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Dim ArrPos(), ArrNeg(), StrOut As String

Function VidSent2(Comp As Boolean, Judg As Boolean, Resp As Boolean, Cust As Boolean, Safe As Boolean)
ReDim ArrPos(0): ReDim ArrNeg(0): StrOut = ""
If Comp = True Then Call Pos("was compliant") Else Call Neg("was not compliant")
If Judg = True Then Call Pos("had good judgment") Else Call Neg("had bad judment")
If Resp = True Then Call Pos("was responsible") Else Call Neg("was not responsible")
If Cust = True Then Call Pos("showed good customer service") Else Call Neg("showed bad customer service")
If Safe = True Then Call Pos("showed safe practices") Else Call Neg("did not show safe practices")

If UBound(ArrPos) > 0 Then ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = "and " & ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos))
If UBound(ArrNeg) > 0 Then ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = "and " & ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg))

If ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) <> "" Then StrOut = "After viewing the video the individual " & Join(ArrPos(), ", ") & "."

If ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) <> "" Then
  If StrOut = "" Then
    StrOut = "Regrettably, after viewing the video the individual still " & Join(ArrNeg(), ", ") & "."
  Else
    StrOut = StrOut & " Unfortunately, the individual still " & Join(ArrNeg(), ", ") & "."
  End If
End If

VidSent2 = StrOut
End Function

Sub Pos(StrTxt As String)
If ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos) + 1)
ArrPos(UBound(ArrPos)) = StrTxt
End Sub

Sub Neg(StrTxt As String)
If ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg) + 1)
ArrNeg(UBound(ArrNeg)) = StrTxt
End Sub
```

which you would call with code like:

```
Sub Test()
bmRange.Text = VidSent2(True, False, True, True, False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the ElseIf statement is the easiest way to do it.  Here's an example.

```
If Range(“A5”) <= 50 Then
    Range (“A6”).Value = “Failing Grade”
Else If Range (“A5”) <= 80 Then 
    Range(“A6”).Value = “Passing Grade”
Else 
    Range(“A6”).Value = “Outstanding Grade”
End If
```

Comment: The required code is for Word, not Excel